# Relationship Issue between two tables in Power BI (Ambiguity issue)

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

Have the following tables in the Power BI data model:

1.       Transaction

| Buyer | Manufacture | TransactionAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Harrison | Patrick | 50 |
| Harrison | Thomas | 40 |
| Harrison | Jack | 90 |
| Aliza | Patrick | 82 |
| Aliza | Thomas | 70 |

2.       Manufacturer

| Manufacturer | Regions |
| --- | --- |
| Patrick | Western Australia |
| Thomas | Northern Territory |
| Jack | New South Wales |

3.       Buyer

| Buyer | Regions |
| --- | --- |
| Harrison | Hunter Valley |
| Aliza | Barossa Valley |

**The requirement:**

when I select the relevant region want to show the corresponding total transaction amount on the card.

The slicer should include all the regions that came from both buyers and manufacturers.
[image]

Created the other table Regions, using the following query and added the relationships as follows:

```
Regions =
CALCULATETABLE (
    UNION (
        SUMMARIZE ( Buyer, Buyer[Regions] ),
        SUMMARIZE ( Manufacture, Manufacture[Regions] )
    )
)
```

[image]

**Problem:**
Can't create an active relationship between Buyer and Region. Therefore, unable to filter the transaction amount correctly.

[image]

**Therefore, I expected the correct way to solved this issue without changing the data model and relationships among the Buyer, manufacturer and Transaction tables**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your production model you should make sure your relationships from your `Regions` table are 1-to-many against your `Manufacturer` and `Buyer` table. Furthermore, the DAX expression you have used to construct your `Regions` table is not great, consider changing to:

```
Regions = 
DISTINCT ( 
    UNION ( 
        DISTINCT ( Manufacturer[Regions] ) , 
        DISTINCT ( Buyer[Regions] ) 
    )
)
```

Lastly we arrive at your question: How to get around the fact that only one of the relationships from `Region` can be active, to avoid model ambiguity issues, i.e. that filters from your `Region` table cannot have two possible filter propagation routes toward your `Transaction` table.

To solve this issue, without changing your datamodel as you request, we need to write a fairly advanced measure that introduces a couple of variables to store the `Regions` values that are active in your `Buyer` and `Manufacturer` tables, given a certain slicer selection on the column `Regions[Regions]`. Furthermore, the variables will be used to filter the `Transaction` table to ensure that we only evaluate each row in `Transaction` once.

The code below assumes that the table that has an **inactive** relationship with `Regions` is the `Buyers` table, as in your data model:

```
Transaction Amount =
VAR _buyers =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Buyer[Buyer] ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Regions[Regions], Buyer[Regions] )
    )
VAR _manu =
    VALUES ( Manufacturer[Manufacture] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Transaction' ),
            'Transaction'[Buyer] IN _buyers
              || 'Transaction'[Manufacture] IN _manu
        ),
        'Transaction'[TransactionAmount]
    )
```

To allow for multiple selections (e.g. `Hunter Valley` **and** `Northern Territory`) we must calculate both buyers and manufacturers that are selected separately.

To calculate which buyers are active, we need to output the `VALUES` of buyers in the `Buyers` table that correspond to the `Regions[Regions]` selection. Since this relationship is **inactive** we need to use `CALCULATETABLE` to invoke the special `USERELATIONSHIP` function.

For manufacturers, this is much easier since we do not need to change our filtering context to use an inactive relationship, so here `VALUES` alone will produce the correct result.

To finalize, we use an iterator (`SUMX`) over the `Transactions` table, where we sum up the `TransactionAmount` for all rows where the corresponding `Transaction[Buyer]` value is in the list of selected buyers, **OR** the `Transaction[Manufacturer]` value is in the list of selected manufacturers.